# ROR c9 environment windows enviroment - bundle install won't run

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundle

Deployment to Heroku – can’t successfully run ‘bundle install’.
I am using c9 and using a windows PC
Reason is version mismatch between what is installed/possible to install on my computer and what is available on c9.
When searching for matching ruby version that is on both c9 and available for windows download reveals no match. 
Hence, I believe,  when running ‘bundle install’ in c9 environment I get a bundle install error no matter what version of Ruby I am using
e.g. if version is a c9 version of ruby but not on my computer I get
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'ruby (= 2.2.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Also same sort of error if on my computer but not available in c9
What do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

something changed somewhere, I have no idea what, and I can now push to both the c9 and Heroku environments without issue.